# TypeScript npm typings feature changes import semantics

Tags: typescript

When importing a typings (`.d.ts`) file using the `import x = require('...')` pattern the semantics change when a package.json
[typings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages)
entry is used.

For example, the following declaration file imports successfully when no
package.json `typings` entry is used but it generates error TS2656
(`Exported external package typings file is not a module`) when used
with a `typings` entry:

```
declare module 'mymodule' {
  export function myfunc(source: string): string;
}
```

Whereas the same file minus `declare module {}` imports successfully
when used with a package.json `typings` entry but generates error
TS2307 (`Cannot find module`) when used without a `typings` entry.

```
export function myfunc(source: string): string;
```

Why the change in semantics?

It looks like if you use the new npm typings feature you will have to
maintain both npm and non-npm versions of your typings files.

I hit this while trying to use a projects typings file within the
project itself (TypeScript does not look  in the current project's
package.json for `typings` entries, it seems to confine it's search
to`./node_modules`).

Tested with TypeScript 1.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages), the `typings` key in package.json is an analogue for the `main` key which points to a single Node.js module. As such, the `d.ts` file pointed to by `typings` is *also* expected to be a single exported module declaration, not a d.ts bundle.

The specific rationale given by the documentation is:

> The rationale is that **typings should not bring new compatible sources** to the set of compiled files; otherwise source files (i.e. `.ts` files) will be considered by the compiler as part of the user code and will be compiled, and outputs in the package can be overwritten with the resulting `.js` outputs.
>
> Additionally, **loading typings should not pollute global scope** by bringing potentially conflicting entries from different version of the same library. Modules have their own scope, and do not pollute the global namespace, if your typings file is not a module, it will be polluting the user global scope, and will cause conflicts with other packages that depend on your package. Similarly `/// <references ... />` can bring global declarations into the global scope and should be avoided.

(Personally, like you, I think this implementation is totally wrong and silly. The `typings` key *should* have pointed to a single file containing multiple relative `declare module './foo' { … }` declarations describing the entire package, as a means of avoiding pollution of the filesystem with tons of TypeScript-specific files. Unfortunately, that ship has sailed at this point, so your package just has to have a ton of TypeScript-specific `d.ts` files side-by-side with your JavaScript modules, plus this redundant description of the main module’s typing.)

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my confusion, I think I'll just avoid using the `typings` key for now so I don't have to maintain two (virtually identical) `.d.ts` files.

Comment: If this does answer the question I would appreciate it if you would mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!